# Java GWT how to write the file path when applying custom celltable/datagrid css styles

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid, classpath, filepath

I am using java GWT 2.4 to write a web application.

I want to append custom css style to DataGrid, but I have problem writing the css file path.
The following is my code:

```
 interface DataGridResources extends DataGrid.Resources
 {
  @Source(value = { DataGrid.Style.DEFAULT_CSS,
  "filepath/myDataGridStyle.css" })  // I should put the correct css file path here. 
  DataGrid.Style dataGridStyle();
 }
```

myDataGridStyle.css file is not in the same file as my interface class.
Basically the files distribution is the following:

MyWebProject

->src

---> com.test.javafiles

------> test1.java

------> test2.java

->war (in the same level of src file)

---> WEB-INF

---> myDataGrid.css    (this is where my css file locates. it is right under war file. All css styles are in this files.)

The myDataGrid.css is under the WAR file which is in under the root of my project file. So my question is how can I redirect the source file path to the correct location.

my css file is put in WAR file which is the same level as src files. For example, my interface file is put in myproject/src/com/test/javafiles. my myDataGridStyle.css is put in myproject/war/myDataGridStyle.css. How can I write the file path for this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, to put the *.css file in the war folder. The *.css file must reside in a java package (I prefer to put it in the same package as the interface, that makes it possible to relatively reference the file). The css file will be compiled into your GWT app. That's why it isn't necessary to have your css file available in the war. Another reason is the fact that css resources can use special constructs in the css code that are replaced by the compiler. But it's not possible to use these inSee [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle) for details.

So it should look like this:

```
 interface DataGridResources extends DataGrid.Resources
 {
  @Source(value = { DataGrid.Style.DEFAULT_CSS,
  "myDataGridStyle.css" })  // I should put the correct css file path here. 
  DataGrid.Style dataGridStyle();
 }
```

and:

->src

---> com.test.javafiles

------> test1.java

------> test2.java

------> myDataGrid.css